# Динамическое добавление View в LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Хочу добавлять в  LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

вот это view

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar_element"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_separator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBackgroundDarckGrey"
    />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_separator">
        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar_friend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/main_activity_progress_bar_background"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_lock"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

В коде делаю следующе:

```
LinearLayout progressConteiner = (LinearLayout) friendCase.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_container);
View progressElement = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_activity_progress_element,null);

progressConteiner.addView(progressElement);
progressConteiner.addView(progressElement);
```

При добавлении второго элемента ловлю вот это:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

**UPD:**

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends RelativeLayout {


    public CustomProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context, null);

        View rootView = inflate(context, R.layout.main_activity_progress_element, this);


        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_friend);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(55);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    }
}
```

добавляю так, но добавляется только один элемент

```
LinearLayout progressConteiner = (LinearLayout) friendCase.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_container);

progressConteiner.addView(new CustomProgressBar(this));
progressConteiner.addView(new CustomProgressBar(this));
```

Comment: Всё верно, потому что второй элемент- это первый элемент, т.е. один и тот же. Вам следует создать кастомное view, заинфлэйтить вашу разметку в нем. И уже перед добавлением в ваш layout, инициализировать каждый раз ее как новый объект.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид я попробовал, обновил ответ, все равно добавляется только один елемент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так теперь попробуйте переделать:

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends RelativeLayout {


    public CustomProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rootView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity_progress_element, this);

        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_friend);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(55);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: я вроде так же и делал! Проблема была в том что первая кнопка занимала все пространство, я добавил  params.weight = 1  и все решилось)

Answer (score 2):

Вы добавляете один и тот же LinearLayout.
Создавайте динамически LinearLayout и добавляйте родителю.

```
progressConteiner.addView(createView(this));

public View createView(Context context){
     LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
     return linearLayout;
}
```

Comment: Вы имели ввиду что  я  в один и тот же LinearLayout  добавляю, или что один и тот же елемент ( progress_bar_element ) добавляю?

Comment: тот же елемент LinearLayout

Comment: не понял, что  я должен каждый раз создавать, обьект который добавляю или обьект В который добавляю. Потому что в вашем примере одно, а получается другое!

Comment: Вот так создавай новый View: LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
LayoutParams linearLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
linearLayout.setLayoutParam(linearLayoutParam);